# looping array of object inside for loop its only taking last condition in javascript

Tags: javascript

Trying below code but not getting expected output
I am expecting below output

```
[{"label":"one","value":"1","disabled":true},{"label":"two","value":"2","disabled":true},{"label":"three","value":"3","disabled":false},{"label":"four","value":"4","disabled":false},{"label":"five","value":"5","disabled":false},{"label":"six","value":"6","disabled":true}]

// ---

var A1 = [ {label:"one", value:"1"}, {label:"two", value:"2"},  {label:"six", value:"6"}]; 
var A2 = [ {label:"one", value:"1","disabled":false}, {label:"two", value:"2","disabled":false}, {label:"three", value:"3","disabled":false}, {label:"four", value:"4","disabled":false}, {label:"five", value:"5","disabled":false}, {label:"six", value:"6","disabled":false}]; 

   for(let i = 0 ; i <A2.length; i++){
      for(let j = 0; j < A1.length; j++){
        if(A1[j].value == A2[i].value){
          A2[i].disabled = true;
        }
        else{
              A2[i].disabled = false;                            
        }
      } 
   }

   console.log( JSON.stringify( A2 ) );
```

Comment: You're over-writing the value of `A2[i]` each time through the inner loop - so the final value is only ever a comparison of `A2[i].value` against the value of the `value` property in the last object in `A1`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Is there another way to handle this

Comment: Are you trying to do an array intersect by any chance? Based on your variables - A2 explicitly states that disabled is false - so why would it change to true in your expected output? Sorry - just trying to understand your question here. -- Ignore me! Just re-read what your function was doing there...

Comment: @ShivajiWatekar - see my answer below. Although this is just based on a guess of what you want, based on the desired output - you don't state clearly, so it's possible I'm wrong.

Comment: could you please give us an explanation of what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, the following should do it:

```
for(let i = 0 ; i <A2.length; i++){
   A2[i].disabled = false;
   for(let j = 0; j < A1.length; j++){
     if(A1[j].value == A2[i].value){
       A2[i].disabled = true;
       break;
     }
   } 
}
```

That is - start off with the `false` value (no match), and only set it to `true` if you find a match. (Then `break` out of the inner loop, because there's no need to continue.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative perspective (jQuery option) if you want it. This is just an idea as I am sure this can be written more elegantly :)

```
var A1 = [ {label:"one", value:"1"}, {label:"two", value:"2"},  {label:"six", value:"6"}]; 
var A2 = [ {label:"one", value:"1","disabled":false}, {label:"two", value:"2","disabled":false}, {label:"three", value:"3","disabled":false}, {label:"four", value:"4","disabled":false}, {label:"five", value:"5","disabled":false}, {label:"six", value:"6","disabled":false}]; 

var tempA = new Array();
var resultArray = new Array();
$.each(A1,function(datakey,dataval){
    tempA.push(dataval['label']);
});
$.each(A2,function(datakey,dataval){
if ($.inArray(dataval['label'],tempA)>-1) {
    resultArray.push({'label':dataval['label'],'value':dataval['value'],'disabled':true})}
  else {
    resultArray.push({'label':dataval['label'],'value':dataval['value'],'disabled':false})
  }
});

console.log(resultArray);
```